# Jade Templates Not Linking

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I have 3 `.jade` files each embedded a level deeper than the previous. All files are in the same folder, but only `layout.jade` and `index.jade` are connecting, `inner.jade` isn't showing up when everything is compiled.

The outer most (layout.jade):

```
doctype html
  html
    head
      title= title
      link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
      body
        block content
```

The middle layer (index.jade):

```
extends layout

block content
  div.wrap
    h1= title
      div.content
        div.display

          block innerContent

        div.helper
```

The inner most (inner.jade):

```
extends index

block innerContent
  table(width="600" align="center")
    tr
      td(width="600")
        table(width="600")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `include inner` in your index.jade instead of `block innerContent` and then remove `extends index` from inner.jade.